# Is there a "popup" display mode for the Save to Foursquare button confirmation screen, rather than "modal"?

Tags: foursquare

For the Save to Foursquare button 
(https://foursquare.com/business/brands/offerings/savetofoursquare), Is there a way for the confirmation screen to popup as an external window instead of a modal window after clicking the button? Is there a property or option to do this?

I am currently embedding the Save to Foursquare button in an iframe, which prevents the modal window from displaying properly.

Comment: Not yet, but we're working on it =).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the old foursquare button like this:

```
<iframe src="http://foursquare.com/button.html?vid=4c433baccc410f478fe5ad61&color=dark" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:165px; height:25px;"></iframe>
```

vid is the id of the venue, the options for color are white, dark and blue, and you can use size=small for a smaller button